# How to prevent access to tomcat web application over internet

Tags: java, tomcat, filter

I have deployed a web application and a web service in my tomcat 7 container. Now i have a problem: The web service should be accessible over external ip and the web application not. It should only accessible over intranet. At the moment both application are available online. 
How can i prevent the access over external ip for the application?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you get answer to this... I am also in need of this